# Simple streaming video object recognition

Tags: python, image-processing, video-streaming, computer-vision, video-processing

I'm doing a project where I want to count things in a video based on their colour. For example, I might want to roll marbles past a camera and have a computer count how many green ones there are, and how often they come past.

More specifically, I want to take a video (in practice this will be a streamed video) and identify when an object of certain characteristics takes position in a specified place.

I am fairly familiar with most common languages but mainly in web development, thus image processing is a bit out of my realm. One idea I had was (for example in python), find a good video streaming library, and image processing one, then the calculations shouldn't be too hard from there (check a certain region of the video for a certain range of specified colours). Does this method seem appropriate? If so, what libraries are available?

Answer (score 1):

Since you specified Python, you might want to have a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) which has a [Python interface](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/index.html).